# CiviEvent - changing an event's creator

Tags: civievent

I'm adding new users with limited permissions to an existing CiviCRM site (Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 4.4.7). These users will be allowed to create events, but not edit others' events.

However, there are already events in the site, all created by the same account. I would like to be able to change the creator's id for these events, so that they can be assigned to various new user accounts.

My guess is that the field for this in the database is "created_id" in the "civicrm_event" table. But is there a way to change an event's organiser from the CiviCRM interface?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct about "created_id", but I'm 99% sure there's no way to update this from the CiviCRM UI.  However, you COULD update it from the API Explorer: **Help menu > Developer > API Explorer**.

Comment: I think u can safely upgrade the 99% to 100% :)

Comment: Ok, I see in the demo at http://d45.demo.civicrm.org that the API explorer allows the "setvalue" operation, but in 4.4.7 it's not an option. I'll just update the database manually. This is a one-time operation in my case, anyway.

Comment: if you do a create action with the id set, it's an upgrade of the existing entity (not very intuitively ;)